# Switching axis in multi-line plot

Tags: r, plot, axis, lines

Hello I have a plot with several lines, and I would like to switch the axis x and y. How could I do it? Below is my current plot code

```
plot(ret,x1,type="l",col="blue",ylab="Volatility (%)",
xlab="Expected Return (%)",lwd=4, mgp=c(1.5, 0.5, 0))
lines(ret,x2,col="green",type="l",lwd=2)
lines(x3,col="black",type="l",lwd=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try switching x and y parameters in plot() and lines():

```
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x, y, type = "l")
plot(y, x, type = "l")
lines(rnorm(10), x, type = "l", col = "blue")
```

Change xlab and ylab accordingly...